# How do I get the sum of all the properties?

Tags: node.js

Given:

```
{
  "property1": 10,
  "property2": 20,
  "property3": 30
}
```

I'd like to add a total property of all the properties, like this:

```
{
  "property1": 10,
  "property2": 20,
  "property3": 30,
  "Total": 60
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` and `Object.values()`.

```js
let o = { "property1": 10, "property2": 20, "property3": 30 };
o.Total = Object.values(o).reduce((s,v) => s + +v, 0);
console.log(o);
```

Comment: What does that extra `+` operator beside `v` do here? And you should use `parseInt()` for the value (v) for the best practice and encapsulation.